# Google Translator API and many translation for one word

Tags: java, translation

I am using google-api-translate-java-0.92.jar.

```
Translate.setHttpReferrer("http://translate.google.com/");
        try {
            String translation = Translate.execute("arrangement", Language.ENGLISH, Language.UKRANIAN);
            System.out.println(translation);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

But I get only one translation.
I go to page http://translate.google.com/ and It gives me multiple translation.
How can I get multiple translation from my code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe you can...

Looking at the soucre, it builds up the following URL:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?v=1.0&langpair=en|uk&q=arrangement

which when you look at the JSON response, returns:

```
{"responseData": {"translatedText":"Композиція"}, "responseDetails": null, "responseStatus": 200}
```

As you can see, this is only returning a single word.  The dictionary lookup on the [google translate page](http://translate.google.com/#en|uk|arrangement) must be an additional call to a different service (not part of the translate service)

---

**EDIT**

Using firebug, you can see the request that is being made by the translate page, and you get this URL:

http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=t&text=arrangement&hl=en&sl=en&tl=uk&multires=1&otf=2&pc=0&sc=1

Which returns this:

```
[[["Композиція","arrangement","Kompozytsiya"]],[["noun",["розташування","розміщення","домовленість","аранжування","упорядкування","механізм","оформлення","пристрій","систематизація","монтаж","пристосування","урегулювання","плани","згода","залагода","розв'язання","порозуміння"]]],"en"]
```

However, this extended URL format is not supported by the translate JAR you are using (at least I can't find it in [the source on google code](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/source/browse/trunk/src/)), is not part of the googleapis subdomain, and I'm not even sure it's for public consumption or that calling it directly doesn't violate Googles T&Cs.

But that's how they generate the dictinary list anyway...

Comment: Hi @tim_yates that was very very helpful!! we can get synonyms for words easily by some string processing. Please can you generate same link for 名(some japanese character) to english. Because that would help to understand the parameters hl and sl.

Comment: I get a 403 error when I try that first link after your "Edit" subheading.

Comment: Yup looks like they turned it off

Answer (score 7):

From Google Translate API FAQ (checked: 16 November 2013)

> Is it possible to get **multiple translations** of a word?

The answer:

> **No.** This feature is only available via the web interface at
>   translate.google.com

source: https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/faq#technical

Answer (score 0):

There is an open [enhancement request](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/issues/detail?id=88) for this functionality. So it doesn't look like you're doing anything wrong; the API just doesn't expose that functionality.