# How do I get all meanings of a word from Google Translate (v2)?

Tags: php, google-translate

How can I get all meanings of a word using Google Translate API v2?
I get a response with only one thing like `translatedText => "text"`, but I need to get all meanings of the word.

These are my parameters:

```
'key' => $this->_apiKey,
'target' => $target,
'q' => $data,
'multires' => 1,
'otf' => 1,
'client' => 't',
'multires' => 1,
'pc' => 0,
'sc' => 1
```

Comment: This looks like a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3915844/77782

Comment: yes but this is a google tranaslate api v1 , I Want v2. I can do this with v2

Answer (score 0):

As we can read on [Translate API FAQ](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/faq)

> Is it possible to get multiple translations of a word? No. This
>   feature is only available via the web interface at
>   translate.google.com